# How to substitute a value in an array with an array of values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values, for example

```
$fred = Array('one','two','@group','three','four');
```

and a second array

```
$group = Array('alpha','beta','gamma');
```

Which is the most efficient way to substitute the value '@group' with the values inside $group array? That is, to obtain

```
$expanded_fred = Array('one','two','alpha','beta','gamma','three','four');
```

PS The grouping method has only one level. No nested groups.

Answer (score 2):

First lets use `array_search` to find the key of the `@group` element:

```
$replaceKey = array_search('@group', $fred);
```

Next we'll use `array_splice` to replace the `@group` element with the `$group` array:

```
array_splice($fred, $replaceKey, 1, $group);
```

`$fred` is now your expanded array.

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/qf4ts

Comment: There may be more `@group` in `$fred`.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate the `$fred` to find all `@group` to replace them with `$group`. [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c01c788716b080ddc83a9bb0d8836c52c5552210)

```
$result = [];
$fred = Array('one','two','@group','three','four');
$group = Array('alpha','beta','gamma');
foreach($fred as $value){
    if($value == '@group'){
        $result = array_merge($result,$group);
    }else{
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```